# Most efficient way to strip out all CSS media-queries?

Tags: css

This might be a weird question, but I am using a CSS layout that uses some heavy media queries,  I want to keep using the layout but strip out ALL existing media-queries, and design that part myself.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Right now I'm thinking I need to first unminify the css (any suggestions on a good tool to do that would be appreciated), and then search for something like "@media screen and (max-width:480px)" and delete all the media-queries I don't want?

The above seems like a time consuming process, I was wondering if there is some tool that exists where I can load up the website and then auto strip every CSS that is not being used including media-queries.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old but I just came across it, there's a Node Package which works quite well for this sort of situation called stripmq.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripmq